# Data transfer from one database to another using php and json

Tags: php, database, json, import, fetch

I want to make a data transfer from one database to another using PHP and JSON. The first MySQL connection gets and prints the data (which is working), but the second MySQL connection doesn't insert the data in the 2nd database. I don't know how to execute the INSERT QUERY in order to start filling up the other database(retrieve data from json encode).

This is what I get from the first database:

```
[{"0":"1","productid":"1","1":"0","parent":"0","2":"","language":"","3":"iPod Shuffle","prodname":"iPod Shuffle","4":"1","prodtype":"1","5":"","prodcode":"","6":"","prodfile":"","7":"
```

And here is my UPDATED code:

```
<?php 

include 'config/config.php';
//include(dirname(__FILE__) . "/settings.inc.php");


//database 1
$data = array();

$conn = @mysql_connect($GLOBALS['VCS_CFG']["dbServer"],$GLOBALS['VCS_CFG']["dbUser"], $GLOBALS['VCS_CFG']["dbPass"]);
if ($conn){
    if (mysql_select_db($GLOBALS['VCS_CFG']["dbDatabase"])) {
        $SQL = "SELECT * FROM vc_products";
        $q = mysql_query($SQL);

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q))
        {
            $json_output[] = $row;
        }
        echo json_encode($json_output);
        $data =  json_encode($json_output);                
    }
    mysql_close($conn);
}


 // database 2

$con = @mysql_connect($GLOBALS['_DB_SERVER_'],$GLOBALS['_DB_USER_'], $GLOBALS['_DB_PASSWD_']);
if ($con) { 
    if (mysql_select_db($GLOBALS['_DB_NAME_'])) {


        $sql = "INSERT INTO ps_order_detail(product_name) VALUES('".$data[0][8]."')";  
        $Q = mysql_query($sql);

        foreach ($data as $key => $value)
        {

           $Q -> bind_param(
                  's',   // the types of the data we are about to insert: s = string ( i = int )
                   $value['prodname']

           ); 

            $Q->execute();

        }
         $Q->close();
    }           
     mysql_close($conn);
}  

?>
```

Comment: First and foremost, use PDO instead of mysql_* functions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see you are executing any insert query ¿?
You are just building the string.

Comment: how can I execute the insert query?

Comment: `mysql_query($sql);` after you biuld the $sql string.

Comment: thanks but i dont know how to use the json output in order to import the data  into the other database. Actually i dont what to write at the INSERT query.

Answer (score 0):

A few problems:

- You are encoding twice instead of encoding and decoding;
- You need to add error handling (PDO and mysqli can throw exceptions, very useful);
- You need to get rid of the error supressor operator `@`;
- You should switch to PDO or mysqli and prepared statements to avoid sql injection problems and because the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.

Not related, but why would you encode and decode to json in the same script when you really want to use the original array?